# SQL Server: query syntax for what seems to be an INSERT...SELECT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to run a query from here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3083381. But I'm getting an incorrect syntax error at `table`.

```
insert into dbChangeTrackingMetadata.dbo.t_SYSCOMMITTABLE
SELECT commit_ts, xdes_id, commit_lbn, commit_csn, commit_time
FROM OpenRowset (table SYSCOMMITTABLE, db_id (), 0, 0)
```

This seems to be a MySQL equivalent of an `INSERT...SELECT` query, but I'm not sure if I'm following the last line. Can someone shine some light onto me?

Comment: In SQL Server you would need a table alias after the function call.

Comment: That's a system table. Why are making insert to it?

Comment: @Rahul, there is apparently a bug in the SQL server we're using, and it crashed a DB while trying to back it up. More info in that link in OP. Excuse my noobness, but are `OpenRowset` and `SYSCOMITTABLE` both system tables in MS SQL?

Comment: OPENROWSET is a SQL Server Function. sys.syscommittab is a system table.

Comment: This is an internal call that only system objects can make. [`OPENROWSET()` is a function you can use](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx), but you can't use this specific syntax in your own queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code mentioned in the KB article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3083381 can be executed only using a Dedicated Administrator Connection, when SQL Server is started in Single-User mode.

The "OPENROWSET (TABLE ...)" syntax is an internal system call, that can be   executed (when SQL Server is started normally) only by system objects.

The allowed syntaxes of OPENROWSET look like these:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\WINDOWS\system.ini', SINGLE_CLOB) t

SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=.;Trusted_Connection=yes;', 'SELECT * FROM sysdatabases') t
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx for details about OPENROWSET.